# Efficiency of extraction of aluminum from aluminum hydroxide

Tags: batteries, aluminium

This is regarding [aluminum air batteries](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium%E2%80%93air_battery)

Since they are rechargeable, in order to "recharge" the batteries we need reswap the aluminium cathode with aluminum hydroxide which is formed.

That aluminum hydroxide needs to be processed to extraxt aluminium.

How efficient is extraction of Aluminum from Aluminum hydroxide?

What is the efficiency of aluminum air batteries, assuming swapping takes no energy?